# How do I convert range of openpyxl cells to pandas dataframe without looping though all cells?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

Openpyxl supports converting an entire worksheet of an excel 2010 workbook to a pandas dataframe. I want to select a subset of those cells, using Excel's native indices, and convert that block of cells to a dataframe. Openpyxl's documentation on working with pandas does not help: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

I am trying to avoid 1) Looping through all rows and columns in the data, since that's inefficient 2) removing this cells from the dataframe after creation instead, and 3) Pandas' read_excel module, since it does not seem to support specifying the range in Excel's native indices.

```
#This converts an entire workbook to a pandas dataframe
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as px

Work_Book = px.load_workbook(filename='MyBook.xlsx')
Work_Sheet = Work_Book['Sheet1']
df = pd.DataFrame(Work_Sheet.values)

#This produces a tuple of cells. Calling pd.DataFrame on it returns
#"ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!"
Cell_Range = Work_Sheet['B2:D4']

#This is the only way I currently know to convert Cell_Range to a Pandas 
# DataFrame. I'm trying to avoid these nested loops.
row_list = []
for row in Cell_Range:
    col_list = []
    for col in row:
        col_list.append(col.value)
    row_list.append(col_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
```

I am trying to find the most efficient way to convert the Cell_Range object above into a pandas dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe PS. please don't alias openpyxl for importing.

Comment: @CharlieClark   I see that it covers converting ws.values to a dataframe, but don't understand how that translates to a cellrange within the worksheet. That might just be my lack of familiarity with the package, though. Can you explain where you think that provides an answer?

Comment: @CharlieClark you are absolutely right about not aliasing openpyxl.  However, your comment is otherwide unresponsive as the documentation gives absolutely NO answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Work_Sheet.values will give you a generator. Turn it into a list to generate a list of tuples, with first tuple having the headers.
To covert it into dataframe, do the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(Work_Sheet.values))
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
df = df.iloc[1:,].reset_index(drop=True)
```